# How to check if a JsonNode is a single element or an Array in Java?

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

I am traversing a json response with JsonNode (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)

How can I check if a given JsonNode is a single element or an Array?, because I need to traverse it deeper, and update some values (for example, the name value)

I can have a json response like this: (with a single element)

```
{  person: {
      name: "name1",
      address: "address1"
   } 
}
```

or I can have a json response like this: (with a )

```
{  "person": [ 
       {
         "name": "name1",
         "address": "address1"
       }, 
       {
         "name": "name2",
         "address": "address2"
       }
   ]
}
```

For an single element, I have this code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
JsonNode personNode = root.findPath("person");
if(!personRootNode.isMissingNode()) 
   ((ObjectNode)nameNode).put("name","UPDATED NAME");
```

And, for an array element, I have this code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
JsonNode personNode = root.findPath("person");
if(!personNode .isMissingNode()) 
   for(JsonNode node: personRootNode){
      if(!node.isMissingNode()) {
         ((ObjectNode)node).put("name","UPDATED NAME");
      }
   }
```

I want to mix the logic in a single place, because the unique difference is the for loop

I can wrap the replace logic in a function/method. **But how do I check if the current node is an element or an array?**

Comment: `personNode.isArray()` is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: Please **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#method_summary), and you'd have found a slew of `isXxx()` methods to determine the node type.

Comment: Yeah, Im sorry. I thaugh it was more complex, but luckly it was easy.

Answer (score 7):

You can call isArray() function on JsonNode object. For example :

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(s2);

    JsonNode personNode = root.findPath("person");

    if(personNode.isArray()) {

       ///array found

    } else {

    // non-array element

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I thaugh it was more harder to determine the type of node.

Answer (score 0):

use the below method. Enter the JSONObject to check and node name.(used the org.json.JSONObject)

```
private void checkNodeStatus(JSONObject jsonObject, String node) {
    if (jsonObject.optJSONArray(node) != null) {
    } else if (jsonObject.optString(node) != null) {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        array.put(jsonObject.getJSONObject(node));
        jsonObject = jsonObject.put(node, array);
    } else {
        System.out.println("error in checkNodeStatus > node : " + node);
    }
}
```

if It is a JSONObject, It converts to JSONArray.